# Работа с параметрами объекта в массиве

Tags: java

```
public class School {

    private int education = 0;
    private int space = 20;
    private int cost = 0;
    private String name = " ";

    //-----CONSTRUCTOR------

    public School(int education, int space, int cost, String name)
    {
       this.cost = cost;
       this.space = space;
       this.education = education;
       this.name = name;
    }


    //----SETTERS-----------


    public void setEducation(int education) {
        this.education = education;
    }

    public void setSpace(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    //-----GETTERS----------


    public int getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    public int getSpace() {
        return space;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Задача такая: Этот класс находит объект, перебирая массив, с максимальным значением education, затем вычитает из параметра space найденного объекта кол-во children

```
public class VeryRichFamilys {

SchoolBoard sclb = new SchoolBoard();

private int children = 7;    

public void chooseSchool()
{
        for (int i = 0; i<sclb.scli.size(); i++) {
            sclb.scli.get(Math.max(0, sclb.scli.get(i).getEducation())).setSpace(sclb.scli.get(i).getSpace()-children);
        }
}
```

-----------------Класс с массивом

```
  public class SchoolBoard {

  public ArrayList<School> scli = new ArrayList<>();

  public SchoolBoard() {
    scli.add(new School(0,20,0,"Ugly"));
    scli.add(new School(30,20,50,"Normal"));
    scli.add(new School(50,20,100,"Best"));
  }
```

при использовании метода `chooseSchool()` выдает ошибку

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 3   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)   at
>   Population.VeryRichFamilys.chooseSchool(VeryRichFamilys.java:27)  at
>   Frame.Interface$1.actionPerformed(Interface.java:80)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: А вопрос то в чём?

Comment: всё, исправил ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перечитав ваш вопрос несколько раз, я кажется понял что вы хотите сделать и в чем ваша ошибка.

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что вы не ищете элемент с максимальным `education`, вы берете его у текущего элемента `Math.max(0, sclb.scli.get(i).getEducation())` и по этому значению пытаетесь взять элемент из списка школ. В случае когда у школы значение education больше 3(в вашем случае это 30 у второй школы) вы получаете 
`IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

И так, в Java 8 на стримах это можно сделать так:

```
// находим элемент с максимальным параметром education
Optional<School> max = sclb.scli.stream().max( (el1, el2) -> el1.getEducation() - el2.getEducation() );
// проверяем, что такой элемент найден
if (max.isPresent()) {
    School school = max.get();
    // изменяем у него параметр space
    school.setSpace(school.getSpace() - children);
}
```

Если же вы не можете использовать Java 8, то можно это сделать так:

```
School maxSchool = null;
// находим элемент с максимальным параметром education
for (School school : sclb.scli) {
    if (maxSchool == null) {
        maxSchool = school;
    } else if (maxSchool.getEducation() < school.getEducation()) {
        maxSchool = school;
    }
}
// проверяем, что такой элемент найден
if (maxSchool != null) {
    // изменяем у него параметр space
    maxSchool.setSpace(maxSchool.getSpace() - children);
}
```

И еще один вариант, чуть меньше кода:

```
// находим элемент с максимальным параметром education
School maxSchool = Collections.max( list, new Comparator<School>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(School o1, School o2) {
        return o1.getEducation() - o2.getEducation();
    }
} );
// проверяем, что такой элемент найден
if (maxSchool != null) {
    // изменяем у него параметр space
    maxSchool.setSpace(maxSchool.getSpace() - children);
}
```

Comment: Заработало) спасибо тебе большое, что такие ответы шикарные даешь :))) 
Ответь еще на один вопрос: я создал интерфейс для проверки работоспособности. Так вот, если я смотрю значения sclb.scli.get(2).getSpace, то при использовании метода chooseSchool() , значение Space не меняется. Зато оно меняется у объекта maxSchool..)) как решить этот вопрос?)) 
Ты идею понял, что дети выбирают наилучшее образование, и занимают места в школе, но в объектах массива это не отображается.

Comment: @OgneFF я когда это писал, проверял, что значение меняется также в списке, а не только в maxSchool. Возможно вы как-то не так используете мой код или я как-то не так проверял. Вот все три варианта https://ideone.com/zFdnDo значение в списке так же поменялось. Посмотрите, что у вас по-другому сделано.

Comment: привет) помоги мне в другом вопросе..Там одни дауны, ты меня с полуслова понимаешь)

Answer (score 3):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` - это точно выход за пределы массива. Смотрите по stackTrace - `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 3`. Вы берете тридцатый элемент, когда их всего 3.